# Error when running Google Places Autocomplete API

Tags: api, autocomplete

I'm new to the Google Places Autocomplete API, and to development in general but I'm hoping someone can help point me in the right direction.  I've reviewed the Google Places documentation and example.  In trying to duplicate Google's example in order to gain a better understanding (http://code.google.com/apis/maps/documentation/javascript/examples/places-autocomplete.html), I receive the following error when I run it:

"The Google Maps API server rejected your request.  The "sensor" parameter specified in the request must be set to either "true" or "false"."

What's maddening is I do have "sensor" set to "false"!  Please see below for the full page code.  Any advice would be greatly appreciated.

```
<html>
  <head>
    <title>Google Maps JavaScript API v3 Example: Places Autocomplete</title>
    <script src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?sensor=false&libraries=places"
      type="text/javascript"></script>

    <style type="text/css">
      body {
        font-family: sans-serif;
        font-size: 14px;
      }
      #map_canvas {
        height: 400px;
        width: 600px;
        margin-top: 0.6em;
      }
    </style>

    <script type="text/javascript">
        function initialize() {
            var mapOptions = {
                center: new google.maps.LatLng(-33.8688, 151.2195),
                zoom: 13,
                mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
            };
            var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map_canvas'),
          mapOptions);

            var input = document.getElementById('searchTextField');
            var autocomplete = new google.maps.places.Autocomplete(input);

            autocomplete.bindTo('bounds', map);

            var infowindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow();
            var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
                map: map
            });

            google.maps.event.addListener(autocomplete, 'place_changed', function () {
                infowindow.close();
                var place = autocomplete.getPlace();
                if (place.geometry.viewport) {
                    map.fitBounds(place.geometry.viewport);
                } else {
                    map.setCenter(place.geometry.location);
                    map.setZoom(17);  // Why 17? Because it looks good.
                }

                var image = new google.maps.MarkerImage(
              place.icon,
              new google.maps.Size(71, 71),
              new google.maps.Point(0, 0),
              new google.maps.Point(17, 34),
              new google.maps.Size(35, 35));
                marker.setIcon(image);
                marker.setPosition(place.geometry.location);

                var address = '';
                if (place.address_components) {
                    address = [(place.address_components[0] &&
                        place.address_components[0].short_name || ''),
                       (place.address_components[1] &&
                        place.address_components[1].short_name || ''),
                       (place.address_components[2] &&
                        place.address_components[2].short_name || '')
                      ].join(' ');
                }

                infowindow.setContent('<div><strong>' + place.name + '</strong><br>' + address);
                infowindow.open(map, marker);
            });

            // Sets a listener on a radio button to change the filter type on Places
            // Autocomplete.
            function setupClickListener(id, types) {
                var radioButton = document.getElementById(id);
                google.maps.event.addDomListener(radioButton, 'click', function () {
                    autocomplete.setTypes(types);
                });
            }

            setupClickListener('changetype-all', []);
            setupClickListener('changetype-establishment', ['establishment']);
            setupClickListener('changetype-geocode', ['geocode']);
        }
        google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, 'load', initialize);
    </script>
  </head>
  <body>
    <div>
      <input id="searchTextField" type="text" size="50">
      <input type="radio" name="type" id="changetype-all" checked="checked">
      <label for="changetype-all">All</label>

      <input type="radio" name="type" id="changetype-establishment">
      <label for="changetype-establishment">Establishments</label>

      <input type="radio" name="type" id="changetype-geocode">
      <label for="changetype-geocode">Geocodes</label>
    </div>
    <div id="map_canvas"></div>
  </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 3):

Try this script

```
 <script>
  function initialize() {
 var mapOptions = {
  center: new google.maps.LatLng(-33.8688, 151.2195),
  zoom: 13,
  mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
};
var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map_canvas'),
  mapOptions);

var input = document.getElementById('searchTextField');
var autocomplete = new google.maps.places.Autocomplete(input);

autocomplete.bindTo('bounds', map);

var infowindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow();
var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
  map: map
});

google.maps.event.addListener(autocomplete, 'place_changed', function() {
  infowindow.close();
  marker.setVisible(false);
  input.className = '';
  var place = autocomplete.getPlace();
  if (!place.geometry) {
    // Inform the user that the place was not found and return.
    input.className = 'notfound';
    return;
  }

  // If the place has a geometry, then present it on a map.
  if (place.geometry.viewport) {
    map.fitBounds(place.geometry.viewport);
  } else {
    map.setCenter(place.geometry.location);
    map.setZoom(17);  // Why 17? Because it looks good.
  }
  var image = new google.maps.MarkerImage(
      place.icon,
      new google.maps.Size(71, 71),
      new google.maps.Point(0, 0),
      new google.maps.Point(17, 34),
      new google.maps.Size(35, 35));
  marker.setIcon(image);
  marker.setPosition(place.geometry.location);

  var address = '';
  if (place.address_components) {
    address = [
      (place.address_components[0] && place.address_components[0].short_name || ''),
      (place.address_components[1] && place.address_components[1].short_name || ''),
      (place.address_components[2] && place.address_components[2].short_name || '')
    ].join(' ');
  }

  infowindow.setContent('<div><strong>' + place.name + '</strong><br>' + address);
  infowindow.open(map, marker);
});

// Sets a listener on a radio button to change the filter type on Places
// Autocomplete.
function setupClickListener(id, types) {
  var radioButton = document.getElementById(id);
  google.maps.event.addDomListener(radioButton, 'click', function() {
    autocomplete.setTypes(types);
  });
}

setupClickListener('changetype-all', []);
setupClickListener('changetype-establishment', ['establishment']);
setupClickListener('changetype-geocode', ['geocode']);
  }

   google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, 'load', initialize);
    </script>
```

Comment: +1 for 
google.maps.event.addListener(autocomplete, 'place_changed', function()